# Count even steps of 196 algorithm

Tags: atomic-code-golf

In the 196-algorithm one starts from an integer and then adds its reverse to it until a palindrome is reached, like this:

```
start -> 5280
5280 + 0825 = 6105
6105 + 5016 = 11121
11121 + 12111 = 23232
-end-
```

Write a *function* that counts **how many even numbers are visited** before the algorithm ends. Starting and ending numbers are also counted, so, in the example above, visited are consider the numbers: **5280, 6105, 11121, 23232** but *not* 825, 5016 and 12111.

Examples:

```
f(5280) = 2
f(56) = 1
f(59) = 1
f(89) = 13
```

Extended code golf rules apply: shortest number of **instructions and operations** (like +,-,mod,print,while,if,...) wins.

Comment: I see fun fights coming up what exactly is a single instruction/operation in some languages ;-) – I'm having trouble already.

Comment: @Joey: Yes :) but lets try not to be too competitive.

Comment: I'd love to see an APL-solution.

Comment: does a ternary operation count as 1 or 2 operations?

Comment: @gnibbler: I would say 1.

Comment: I find the link http://assemblyrequired.crashworks.org/2009/01/04/fcmp-conditional-moves-for-branchless-math/ interesting!

Comment: if f(5280) visits **5280, 6105, 11121, 23232** seems f(5280) should be 4, and not 2.

Comment: @belisarius: we are interested in *even* numbers only; 5280 and 23232 in this list.

Comment: @Eelvex tnx, sorry, I misread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Mathematica

**5 verbs** ... not sure how to count ...

```
k = FromDigits@Reverse@IntegerDigits[#] &; 
Count[NestWhileList[# + k@# &, #, # != k@# &], _?OddQ] &
```

Answer (score 6):

### Python - 10 operations

```
def f(n):
    q=str(n)
    p=q[::-1]
    return 1-n%2+(q!=p and f(n+long(p)))
```

Comment: I count these: str, ::-1, return, -, %, +, and, f(), +, longp

Comment: @Joey, @Eelvex, 10 it is then

Comment: how come you're using `long()` wouldn't `int()` be shorter?

Comment: @st0le, yeah for normal golf but this is about minimum number of operations so I think it doesn't matter here

Comment: Why don't you count `!=` as an instruction`

Answer (score 4):

Hey, looks like `eval`, for once, isn't forbidden here!

### Perl, 1 instruction

```
sub f { eval << 'EOT' }
  my $n = $_[0];
  my $r = reverse $n;
  return !($n & 1) + ($r eq $n ? 0 : f($n+$r));
EOT
```

Answer (score 3):

## D: 154 Characters, 22 Instructions

```
alias long l;alias string s;l f(l n){l t=!(n&1);auto u=to!s(n);while(u!=to!s(retro(u))){n=to!l(u)+to!l(to!s(retro(u)));if(!(n&1))++t;u=to!s(n);}return t;}
```

More Legibly:

```
alias long l;
alias string s;

l f(l n)
{
    l t = !(n & 1);  //3 instructions
    auto u = to!s(n);  //2 instructions

    while(u != to!s(retro(u)))  //4 instructions
    {
        n = to!l(u) + to!l(to!s(retro(u)));  //6 instructions

        if(!(n & 1))  //3 instructions
            ++t;  //1 instruction

        u = to!s(n);  //2 instructions
    }

    return t;  //1 instruction
}
```

I'm not sure that counted instructions quite right, since that's a bit debatable, and of course, there are lots of instructions going on in the functions which get called. So, ultimately, I'm not sure how reasonable or accurate counting instructions is, but I think that 22 is the total.

Comment: The way you counted seems fair to me.

Answer (score 2):

## Scheme, 18 instructions

I take an instruction to be an opening paren.

```
(define (even-numbers-from-169-algo n)
    (+
        (if (odd? n) 0 1)
        (if (equal? n (num-reverse n))
            0
            (even-numbers-from-169-algo
                (+ n (num-reverse n))))))
(define (num-reverse n)
    (string->number (list->string (reverse (string->list (number->string n))))))
```

Comment: I think "15 instructions" is more fair.

Comment: @Eelvex: Which ones didn't you count? (I'm not going to argue though :))

Comment: (define (list)) and probably I counted something more? I don't know... this instructions thing is a mess ...  :/

Answer (score 2):

### Windows PowerShell, 16 instructions

```
function f($n){
  @(                                   # 1
    $(                                 # 1
      $n % 2                           # 1
      #1     1   1     2    1
      for(;-join"$n"[99..0]-ne$n) {    # 5
        # 1   1   1     2
        $n+=-join"$n"[99..0]           # 5
        $n % 2                         # 1
      }                                #
    ) -eq 0).Count                     # 2
}
```

Notes:

- I counted the following items as one instruction: String expansion (`"$n"`), operators (`-ne`, `%`, `!`, `-join`, `$()`, `@()`), cmdlets (`%`), keywords (`for`).
- I counted indexes as two instructions since it's the index `[]` plus the range operator `..`
- I didn't count the function header.

History:

- 2011-02-15 02:49 (18) First attempt.
- 2011-02-15 02:55 (16) Got rid of the pipeline.

Comment: I don't know about indexes... maybe you should only count the range operator.

Answer (score 2):

### J, 36 characters, 7 instructions

```
+/@:-.@(2&|)@((+`1:@.=|.&.":)"0^:a:)
```

I'm counting both monadic and dyadic verbs as instructions.  Here's a token breakdown to make sure everything is accounted for:

- 3 monadic verbs (6 chars): `-.`, `|.`, `":`
- 4 dyadic verbs (4 chars): `+`, `|`, `+`, `=`
- 0 adverbs (0 chars)
- 10 conjunctions (14 chars): `/`, `@:`, `@`, `&`, `@`, `` ` ``, `@.`, `&.`, `"`, `^:`
- 4 constants (6 chars): 2 1: 0 a:
- 3 parenthesis groups (6 chars)

Demonstration:

```
   +/@:-.@(2&|)@((+`1:@.=|.&.":)"0^:a:) 5280 56 59 89
2 1 1 13
```

The `"0` isn't strictly needed to answer the question, it's just there to make the function more J-like (*i.e.*, able to operate on a whole array at once, as above).  I kept it in as it doesn't go against my instruction count.

Comment: J wins again? :)

Comment: I'm at least expecting a debate-storm of whether or not conjunctions should be counted in ;)  But then again until I understand how the leading entry counts its instructions, my method doesn't seem any less legitimate.

Answer (score 1):

**Java Solution**

```
int countEvenIn196(long n){
        int count=0;
        boolean flag=false;
        while (!flag){  
        for (int i=0; i<(""+n).length(); i++)
            if ((""+n).charAt(i) == (""+n).charAt((""+n).length()-i-1))
                {flag=true;}
            else {flag=false; break;}
        if (n%2==0) count++;
        //n+=reverse(n);
            n+=(Long.parseLong(new StringBuffer(""+n).reverse().toString()));
        }
        return count;
    }
```

Comment: IDEONE: http://www.ideone.com/wZw1t

Comment: 35 instructions by my count.

Comment: Thnx Joey :), how do we count this btw... does it depend on JVM or OS/Kernel or Processor.. am sure all of them have their own distinct executed instructions... I stopped counting when I started thinking about my StringBuffer.reverse().

Answer (score 1):

**Haskell 12 Operations**

```
f n=1-n`rem`2+if q/=p then f(n+read p) else 0 where q=show n;p=reverse q
```

New to Haskell. Need help to reduce it further.

Comment: Good code. Try to use a seperate function and guards instead of an if-then-else, as they don't count as instructions ;) (in my mind)